# Is there a way to get the channel ID that I stored in json and use it in a command? [discord.py]

Tags: discord.py

So I made a setup channel command where my bot will ask what channel do you want that command to be enabled and when you entered #channelname the bot will store the guild id and channel id

```
{
   "712372999125680159":[
      "<#712374015363596319>"
   ]
}
```

in json.

Is there a way to get that channel id `["<#712374015363596319>"]` and apply it to a command?

Comment: If you're storing the channel id as a string extract the ID (number) convert it to int and pass it to `fetch_channel`.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying. Do you have any examples for that so I can learn? :) I don't know if I explained it clearly but what I'm trying to do is get the channel id in that json setup by other servers and use those ids to the commands. I guess one good example would be setting up a command channel. You'll choose a channel (#general), bot will store the server and channel id in json then all the commands would only work in that channel for that server.